# French idiom spelling: l’embarras des richesses?

Tags: expressions, orthographe

We are writing a biography and we need to spell one French idiom correctly. This idiom was used by a very old Russian lady who spoke fluent French (she was born before 1900) who used to say it when she couldn't find a book in her library (she had over 3,500 books). She would look for a book and then say, "Blah, blah, blah" and then would translate the idiom in Russian - "inconvenience from having too much stuff" or "inconvenience from being too rich".

Choices:

a. L'Embarras des richesses (capital L and E)

b. embarras des richesses (no capitals)

c. L'embarras des richesse (lower case e) - I tried google pronunciation, it sounds like it

d. L'embarras de la richesse

Comment: Do you have a little bit more context? What is the sentence, and what are the sentences around it?

Comment: The context: every time she was trying to find a book, she would climb the ladder to reach the top of her library. She would look at all the books - she had a huge library - and she would say that idiom. I just don't remember the exact words. Something that sounds like "Ambara de rishes" and then she would translate - inconvenience from being too rich (or from having too much stuff).

Comment: Only (a) is spelled correctly.

Comment: But that would be without the upper case E, which is used on common names only to really emphasize something, and it's not the case. Or, if you prefer, the c) but with an 's' at the end of 'richesses'.

Comment: embarras is not inconvenience or embarrassment.

Answer (score 6):

[This *Wiktionary* entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embarrassment_of_riches) seems to be saying that the English expression “The embarrassment of riches” (i.e., “[the problem with having] too much of a good thing”) is from a translation of (the title of) the 1726 French play **“L'Embarras DES richesses**”(one "s" in *embarras* and "DES" [richesses]).

According to [this n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=embarras+des+richesses%2Cembarras+de+richesses%2Cembarras+de+richesse%2Cembarras+de+la+richesse&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cembarras%20des%20richesses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembarras%20de%20richesses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembarras%20de%20richesse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembarras%20de%20la%20richesse%3B%2Cc0), "embarras DES richesses" was the version that was most prevalent through about 1917 (which could very well correspond with an important year in the life of the interesting subject of your biography).

However, again according to n-gram, none of the versions of the expression using "richesse/s" come/s close to the frequency of the nearly synonymous expression ["embarras du choix."](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=embarras+des+richesses%2Cembarras+de+richesses%2Cembarras+de+richesse%2Cembarras+de+la+richesse%2Cembarras+du+choix%2Cembarras+de+choix%2Cembarras+des+choix&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cembarras%20des%20richesses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembarras%20de%20richesses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembarras%20de%20richesse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembarras%20de%20la%20richesse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembarras%20du%20choix%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembarras%20de%20choix%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembarras%20des%20choix%3B%2Cc0)

(cf: [This French *reddit* thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/French/comments/35uo66/the_expression_embarras_de_richesse/) also discusses this expression, with implications that the French “version” is actually used by speakers of English and that it’s perhaps not used at all in French-speaking countries.)

Comment: Thank you very much, Papa Poule, however, it does not answer my question because I still do not know if it's des richesses or de richess? The person who used to say it was not an English speaker, she was Russian who spoke fluent French. She didn't speak a word of English.

Comment: @Banana - the correct French would be _des richesses_. "_de richess_" is not correct. But we could help you better with a little bit more context.

Comment: I added a comment to clarify. Thanks for your explanation. So is "l'Embarass des richesses" the correct version then?

Comment: She didn't say "embarass du choix" for sure. Choix sound like "shua" but she said " ambara de riches"

Comment: @Banana - not quite :-) The correct form is "l'embarras des richesses" (2 'r', 1 's' at _embarras_ in French). You can capitalize _embarras_ if you want but I wouldn't - it's just another regular noun. I have no opinion on this capitalization.

Comment: What about l'embarras des richess. Would it be correct?

Comment: Sorry, I keep writing it with two s for some reason. So if I put "l'embaras des richesses" that's the correct version? I can't say "l'embaras des richess"?

Comment: Watch out! :-) 2 'r', 1 's' :-) _l'embarras des richesses_. No other choice.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll just copy and paste to be on the safe side. Merci bien!!!

Comment: @Banana Sorry for the misunderstanding about "l'embarras du **choix**". I didn't mean to suggest at all that your subject said that instead, but only that her 21st century, French-speaking American counterpart escaping the US in 2017 would probably be more familiar with the version using "choix." Also, many thanks to Frank for kindly filling in the many gaps contained in my answer.

Comment: @Papa Poule - thank you very much for your answer! I needed the correct phrase for the publishing company, so I know the difference now! Your answer was perfect, merci!!!

Comment: That thing on Reddit re speakers of English using the expression is simply not true. Sometimes English speakers will throw French phrases into their speech but this is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Peut-être voulait-elle dire:"Ce n'est vraiment pas pratique d'avoir trop d'affaires". "Comment s'y retrouver au milieu de toutes ces choses / tous ce livres? / toute cette richesse?"

Answer (score 0):

> she said "*ambara de riches*"

is what you remember hearing.

So she was saying "(l')embarras des richesses". Most probably *with* the article : "**L'embarras des richesses**". Not putting it makes it implied, and is really a spoken form.
There's no reason to put an upper case for "Embarras" here. You will find it in a tittle (of a play, a book, a chapter) because the first term is an article, so the upper case also goes to the noun that follows.

Equally, **L'embarras de la richesse** ("The inconvenience from being too rich") is quite an equivalent to it ("The inconvenience from having too much stuff / too much wealth"). You can use both forms alternatively. But since there was a play by that tittle, the first form – the one you remember – had some extra meaning in her mouth.

In that context, I would write it followed by a suspension mark or an exclamation mark, depending on her mood, tired or upset.

Answer (score 0):

In such matter, the french idiom is **(c'est) un problème de riches**, what is sometimes translated by "(it's) a first world problem", expression used to minimize complaints about trivial issues by shaming the complainer, or as good-humored self-deprecation.